# EU Blue Card - Poland

Tags: blue-card, poland

I am a Indian national working for a Swiss investment bank at Pune, India. I recently landed my first international job in a new team, within the bank at Wroclaw, Poland. I received a copy of my work-permit today. I plan to fly to Wroclaw in the month of March, 2019. I had a few queries on the EU Blue Card Poland. I tried searching this forum for answers, and couldn't find them, so it would be best to create a new post.

1. How does the karta pobytu(TRC) differ from the EU Blue Card Poland? Can I apply for them, or does my employer need to apply for it? Is there an official site, with more details on EU Blue Card Poland?
2. My spouse plans to travel with me as a dependent. If I get a EU Blue card in Poland, does my spouse have access to the labor market? Does she still need an employer to sponsor a work permit?

Cheers,
Quasar.